# SAML SSO intermittently fails - InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message

Tags: saml

During the SSO flow for my webapp I throw an error on the postback from the IDP:

org.opensaml.common.SAMLException: InResponseToField of the Response doesn't correspond to sent message a39276f2g3bf914ekjhg376ghdhd

I have no idea what is causing this issue as it happens intermittently and is hard to reproduce. Unfortunately for security reasons, I cannot disable this check as described here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-troubleshooting.html

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the intermittent failures is due to how Chrome treats the session cookie during the SAML postback to the app.  In my case, my app is considered a third-party to my IDP, so the cookie is not sent back to after authentication (if you take more than 2 minutes to login), effectively losing the login session.

For reference: https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/. From that page, "Note that the 2-minute window for "Lax+POST" is a temporary intervention and will be removed at some point in the future (some time after the Stable launch of Chrome 80), at which point **cookies involved in these flows will require `SameSite=None` and `Secure` even if under 2 minutes old**."

In my case, my solution looked like this. - In my saml entry point, I included the following:

```
HttpSession session = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getSession();
                    ((HttpServletResponse)response).addHeader("Set-Cookie", "JSESSIONID=" + session.getId() +"; Secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=None; Path=/to/sso/endpoint;");
```